# Magento: Add multiple add to cart buttons and qty fields to product view page

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am currently grouping similarly named products on the product view page using the following:

```
    $model =Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $collection = $model->getCollection();;

    $currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', $currentProduct->getName());

    echo "<table>";
    foreach($collection as $product){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$product->getSKU().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product->getName().'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="'.$product->getProductUrl().'">VIEW THIS PRODUCT</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

However I need to replace the 'view this product' link with an add to cart button and a qty input field. Is this even possible to do by editing only product/view.phtml?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are adding only simple products without any option then

```
.....
foreach($collection as $product){
  <form action="/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $product->getId() ?>" />

    echo $product->getSKU();
    echo $product->getName();

   <input type="text" name="qty" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" />
  </form>
}
```

See [Adding a Product to the Cart via Querystring](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)